# Renaming folders by Filtering "@a"

Tags: regex, batch-file, cmd

I have a parent folder which contains many sub folders with `@a` in their names. Eg,

```
test@atest
@atest@a
@atest2
test3@a
```

I want to batch-rename all folders filtering out the `@a` part.
The desired output should be as follows.

```
testtest
test
test2
nest3
```

Note: There wont be a case where two folders would result in the same names after the filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Batch-files don’t support regexes but you can use [string substitution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html):

`%FOLDER:@a=%` will replace `@a` with an empty string (the part after `=`).

You can process all folders containing `@a` using a `for` loop:

The command [`for /d`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)`%G in (*@a*) do echo %G` will just print them.

NOTE: This will work on command line, you must use `%%G` in a batch-file.

So the script to remove `@a` from all folders’ names:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%G in (*@a*) do (
    set FOLDER=%%G
    move !FOLDER! !FOLDER:@a=!
)
```

The command `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` allows using [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) of variables which is needed in a loop. The variable is surrounded with `!` instead of `%` to be expanded when the line is executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%I in (*) do (
    set NAME=%%I
    set NEW=!FOLDER:@a=!
    move !NAME! !NEW!
)
```

Try it out.